# Photoshop is making GIF too fast

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, animated-gif

I recently got a new computer. I installed Photoshop CC from the same place I got the one I used on my last computer, same version, same everything. I've been trying to gif for a few days now but came across a problem with timing. I have always used 0.05-0.07 as frame delay and it worked just fine, but now I realized any frame delay I insert is too fast. this is 0.07, example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4BXD.jpg), i tried 0.09 and upper and while it does slow, it seems laggy and doesn’t work quite as well as 0.05 has always worked for me. I’ve been giffing for 9 years and never had this problem. I have tried: installing another version of photoshop (cs5) and the same issue occurred; I did reset PS preferences and it also didn't work; don’t know what else to do. I was wondering if any of you could help me or have been through this because I couldn’t find anything online. I'm thinking it might be some computer setting, but I don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The speed a GIF plays at depends on your browser, and hardware. Nothing to do with Photoshop really.  If you set the frame speed faster than your browser can display it then you simply won't notice that it's actually playing slower. You may have simply noticed this now because you have a newer computer that has newer/better/faster hardware.

Comment: @BillyKerr and that would imply all OPs old gifs are in fact too fast. Note that 0.05 is 20 fps and that is fast for a gif indeed nearly movie quality. While classical animation is ony 12 fps

Comment: @joojaa - yes, quite possibly.  I think 12fps is probably what one should aim for, since the vast majority of people probably don't have powerful enough computer hardware to view it any faster anyway.

Comment: @joojaa Also larger GIFs may play considerably slower on some systems compared to smaller GIFs. If more accuracy in speed is required, perhaps a GIF is not the right format. A streaming video might be better.

Comment: I've distilled this info into an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, the speed a GIF plays at depends on your browser and hardware capabilities. Nothing to do with Photoshop really. If you set the frame speed faster than your browser can display it, then you simply won't notice that it's actually playing slower. You may have simply noticed this now because you have a new computer that has newer/better/faster hardware, and which isn't so cluttered yet and so is running more efficiently/faster.

As @joojaa has commented, this suggests that in fact your GIFs were previously set to a speed that was too fast for your browser and old hardware to display at the speed you set them to.

I think 12fps (0.083s) is probably what one should aim for, since the vast majority of people probably don't have powerful enough computer hardware to view it any faster anyway. Also note that larger GIFs may play considerably slower than smaller GIFs, espcially on general consumer grade/older computers.

Ultimately if accuracy in speed or faster framerates are a requirement, then perhaps a GIF is not the right format.  Perhaps consider using a streaming video format instead.